# org.springframework.jdbc DB rollback doesn't revert the state

Tags: java, database, exception, jdbc, rollback

I try to rollback my DB change

the roollback code runs with no exception and yet my DB is dirty with changes.

Am i missing something?

```
    final Connection dbConnection = rulesUiRepository.getConnection();
    dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
    try {

        if (rulesUiRepository.updateRulesUiSnapshot(this.nonSplittedRulesSnapshot) == -1)
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot save ui snapshot to DB");

       ...more code

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("transaction to update db and cofman failed", e);

        //did work
        //dbConnection.rollback();

        throw new Exception("transaction to update db and cofman failed", e);

    } finally {
        //or
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
```

with that code:

```
public synchronized void rollback() throws SQLException {
    try {
        this.txn_known_resolved = true;
        this.inner.rollback();
    } catch (NullPointerException var2) {
        if(this.isDetached()) {
            throw SqlUtils.toSQLException("You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!", var2);
        } else {
            throw var2;
        }
    } catch (Exception var3) {
        if(!this.isDetached()) {
            throw this.parentPooledConnection.handleThrowable(var3);
        } else {
            throw SqlUtils.toSQLException(var3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the rollback commented out? What is your database? What is the actual code sing the connection? What is the state before the execution and after? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. There are way too many unknowns here.

Comment: Why is the rollback commented out? because it didn't work for me
What is your database? org.springframework.jdbc DB rollback doesn't revert the state

Answer (score 0):

Rollbak do rollback since last commit. You have code you didn't show that might do commit implicitly by using @Transactional for example or explicitly and the rollback transaction will be effective only on database transactions after it

Comment: i send commit underneath my code `rulesUiRepository.updateRulesUiSnapshot(this.nonSplittedRulesSnapshot)` it wraps the jdbsc code deep inside

Comment: You can't rollback transaction after you commit. sometimes you can add new update which will rollback the state